# 1С Получить дату записи в регистр накопления из таблицы остатков

Tags: 1с

Есть регистр `ОбепечениеЗаказов` в Управление торговлей 11, задача - получить в запросе необеспеченные позиции (это не сложно) и даты возникновения этих потребностей (с этим проблема). Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что из таблицы остатков нельзя получить период, а в самом регистре `ОбепечениеЗаказов` записи не сгруппированы, зато у каждой есть период. Таким образом, решил обойтись без системной таблицы остатков и написал свою с периодом:

```
ВЫБРАТЬ
    ОбеспечениеЗаказов.Номенклатура,
    ОбеспечениеЗаказов.Назначение,
    СУММА(ОбеспечениеЗаказов.Потребность) КАК Заказано,
    СУММА(ОбеспечениеЗаказов.КЗаказу) КАК КОбеспечению,
    СУММА(ОбеспечениеЗаказов.Потребность) - СУММА(ОбеспечениеЗаказов.КЗаказу) КАК Обеспечено,
    МИНИМУМ(ОбеспечениеЗаказов.Период) КАК Дата
ПОМЕСТИТЬ ОбеспечениеЗаказовОстатки
ИЗ
    РегистрНакопления.ОбеспечениеЗаказов КАК ОбеспечениеЗаказов

СГРУППИРОВАТЬ ПО
    ОбеспечениеЗаказов.Номенклатура,
    ОбеспечениеЗаказов.Назначение

ИМЕЮЩИЕ
    СУММА(ОбеспечениеЗаказов.КЗаказу) > 0
```